# How to associate a django url with a bootstrap modal popup

Tags: django, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a django view which create an form within a modal popup. When clicking to `li`that triger the modal, nothing happen. I seems it is because I am not in the page.
Because when I was in another page, I see the popup firing. Is it possible to add url cooresponding to the view in the modal button

here is my navbar.html

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#formModal" 
        href="{% url 'create_campaign_naming_tool' %}">Modal</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My form template:

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">      

      </div>

       <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form}}
          <!-- Modal footer -->
           <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="button">Create</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```